# IE sets :focus on lots of random elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer, focus

It seems that IE (even 10) sets the `:focus` pseudo-class on lots of elements that shouldn't really be focusable. No other browser does this, but perhaps my CSS is "wrong" anyway. Without adding proper classes and tabindex to my HTML elements, is there a way to prevent IE from focusing DIVs that do not have a tabindex?

CSS:

```
:focus {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
    /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: You could change the way focus looks, to make it invisible, then set it to look the way you want for the elements you need.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I'm working with a really crappy codebase that is completely unorganized, gigantic, and inconsistent. So, I'd have to hunt down every element and add proper classes etc. to make sure I didn't accidentally catch elements that shouldn't get the focus styles.

Comment: :focus is not often used. It shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 0):

you might give this a try

```
:focus[tabindex] {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
}
```

you can even set different index results:

```
:focus[tabindex='1'] {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
}
```

Comment: this wont stop the browser from trying to focus the elements unfortunately, but nothing will outside of trying to take it over through javascript/jquery or something. This will only deal with the effect applied to focused items. Are these divs wrapped in <a> tags or something?